# Why is my plot of the power of a negative number failing?

Tags: plotting

I would like plot something like the power of a negative value. However the graph is empty. Why is that?

My code is like

```
Plot[{(-2)^n} {n, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. But even corrected you would obtain imaginary components, which Plot does not like.

Comment: Except for integer values of `n`, `-2^n` takes complex values, which will not be plotted by `Plot`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[(-2)^n], Im[(-2)^n]}, {n, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: Or, in v10.1 and later `ParametricPlot[ReIm[(-2)^n], {n, 1, 3}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[{Re, Im, Abs, Arg}[(-2)^n]], {n, 1, 3}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Or

```
ListLogPlot@Table[(-2)^n, {n, -10, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, corrected

Answer (score 1):

When a plot fails, it is often useful to look at a table of the values function being for a mesh over the domain of the plot. In your case,

```
Table[(-2)^n, {n, 1, 3, .1}] // Chop
```

reveals the problem by returning

```
 {-2., -1.85863 - 1.35038 I, -0.815501 - 2.50985 I, 0.936764 - 2.88306 I, 
  2.81716 - 2.04679 I, 4., 3.71727 + 2.70075 I, 1.631 + 5.01971 I, 
  -1.87353 + 5.76613 I, -5.63432 + 4.09357 I, -8.}
```

`Plot` can not plot the complex numbers in the list.

Perhaps what you really wanted was

```
ListPlot[Table[(-2)^n, {n, 3}]]
```

[image: plot]